# Alias .\SQLEXPRESS to (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB

Tags: sql-server

I have `.\SQLEXPRESS` installed, but the code assumes that I have a server named `(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB`.

How do I create an alias so that I don't have to install `SQLLocalDb` ?

Answer (score 5):

1. Start Sql Server configuration manager
2. Add an alias for the 64-bit SQL Native Client Configuration with the following parameters (see screenshot). Try the 32-bit if this doesn't work.

[image: Add alias]

Properties screen:

```
Alias Name - (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB
Pipe Name  - \\.\pipe\MSSQL$sqlexpress\sql\query
Protocol   - Named Pipes
Server     - .\SQLEXPRESS
```

There is an additional step if you have `(LocalDB)\v11.0`
installed but you want to create an alias `(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB`.
You should first work out the pipe name for (LocalDB)\v11.0 as 
it varies from machine to machine.

```
C:\>"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\sqllocaldb.exe" info v11.0
Name:               v11.0
Version:            11.0.2318.0
Shared name:
Owner:              SOMEDOMAIN\Some.User
Auto-create:        Yes
State:              Running
Last start time:    13/01/2016 1:38:36 PM
Instance pipe name: np:\\.\pipe\LOCALDB#14A493ED\tsql\query
```

Comment: thx! used it to create an alias for the `(localDB)\MSSQLLocalDB` to `localhost`

Answer (score 0):

To create alias like `(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB` you can use [SqlLocalDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqllocaldb-utility) and [cliconfg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/create-or-delete-a-server-alias-for-use-by-a-client) command line utilities.

1. Check what aliases you have now by running command `sqllocaldb info` to list the aliases configured already:

[image]

2. Run `sqllocaldb create MSSQLLocalDB` to create `(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB` alias

[image]

Now you can use created `(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB` alias

3. *(optional) Make sure you enabled like `TCP/IP` and `Named Pipes` protocols for you SQLEXPRESS instance by running command `cliconfg` which opens `SQL Server Client Network Utility` if you see the error below*

`A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)`

[image]