# Sharing database project in TFS

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, tfs

I created a database project as part of my solution with scripts for my tables. I'm using database first, so all I do is run the project to build/deploy my tables to the database.

I'm working with a few others so I checked the SQL project into TFS.

So the other people can get the solution, run the SQL project and generate the local database for themselves.

The problem is, it might generate them under another local instance. For instance, on my home computer, it generated it under (localdb)\Projects, but on my laptop, under (localdb)\ProjectsV12.

This breaks the connection strings (which of course can be fixed). But this leaves me wondering, is there a better way to develop the SQL project collaboratively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the SQL code under source control then everyone can open that solution to edit/create copies of the database. Ideally you have an automated process but that does not work for local dev.

Since sharing code is a bad idea and you have expressed that the database is used by more than one solution I would consider packaging and distributing it.

If you create a SSDT database project you can compile your database into a package that can upgrade any instance. You can then share that .dacpac output easily.

You might even what to share it with Nuget so that each dependency is automatically updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a SQL alias name to standardize the connection string across developer machines.

[Alias .\SQLEXPRESS to (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34758006/alias-sqlexpress-to-localdb-mssqllocaldb)